# soft tabs showing up as hard tabs, spaces converted to hard tabs

Tags: cloud9-ide

I have soft tabs enabled, but not only is the editor putting actual tabs in instead of spaces, if I type [space][space], it converts it to a tab. I've read that the editor tries to read existing files to guess your settings (I have Autodetect turned off if that matters), so I tried with a new file. Here is the relevant section of my settings file (which I edited through the GUI):

```
"ace": {
    "@guessTabSize": false,
    "@newLineMode": "unix",
    "@tabSize": 2,
    "@useSoftTabs": true
},
```

When I turn off soft tabs, it stops converting spaces into tabs, but either way, when I hit enter at the end of a line, autoindent uses a tab instead of spaces.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cloud9 doesn't have any code that can convert two spaces into a tab.
When soft tabs is enabled it moves cursor as if two spaces is a tab, but that doesn't change characters in the file.
Enter at the end of line copies indentation from that line, and doesn't depend on tab settings.

Comment: Well, that's interesting, and not what I expected (obviously), especially when I hit backspace once and it takes out two spaces. But when I copy/paste to another editor, the spaces are there. Thanks.